# scope variable is not accessed in angularjs in internet explorer

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-scope, directive

I have a custom directive in which i am calculating width and assigning it into scope variable. That scope variable is being accessed in html which is working fine in firefox and chrome. But not in Internet explorer.

code in controller

```
cellWidth: 160 // property of an object
```

Code in directive

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++) {
    scope.columnMapping.columns[i].tempCellWidth = scope.columnMapping.columns[i].cellWidth * 100) / tableWidth;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width: {{column.tempCellWidth}}%;"> {{columnName}} </div> // IE does not evaluate this..
```

IE shows width: {{column.tempCellWidth}}% while inspecting an element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ng-style` attribute instead of `style` directly.

```
<div ng-style="{ width: column.tempCellWidth }"> {{columnName}} </div>
```

Also to append the percentage sign (%), you should do it in your `for` loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++) {
    scope.columnMapping.columns[i].tempCellWidth = (scope.columnMapping.columns[i].cellWidth * 100) / tableWidth) + '%';
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details what exactly is not working ? Do you have the `style width` attribute set with a value on IE ?

Comment: Hey, it worked...I did exactly the same thing...(%) in loop ...thanks man..GLAD